# sfdx plugins are not getting installed via docker

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin

We are using below script to install sfdx plugins on top of Jenkins via below docker file.

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.263.3
USER root

RUN mkdir /.cache /.sf

RUN chown jenkins.jenkins /.cache -R

RUN chown jenkins.jenkins /.sf -R

RUN chmod 757 /.cache /.sf -R

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git ant xmlstarlet xz-utils && \
wget https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/sfdx/channels/stable/sfdx-linux-x64.tar.xz && \
tar xJf sfdx-linux-x64.tar.xz --strip-components 1
RUN sfdx --version

RUN echo y | sfdx plugins:install sfdx-git-delta

RUN sfdx plugins

USER jenkins
```

---

However, the plugins are not getting installed. There are no installation errors as well.

Below is the section of build from terminal:
[image]

Also, this is not an issue with sgd plugin. I tried installing other plugins as well, with same result.

Any help is appreciated as we are trying to fix it from last week.

Answer (score 0):

Compared to my docker where CLI plugins get installed successfully, could it be that you are missing single quotes around the 'y'?

Comment: I think no, because it saying "installed v5.3.0". Can you share you docker file.

Comment: Also, we tried using nodejs image and they are getting installed correctly. Check below:
https://github.com/scolladon/sfdx-git-delta/issues/315#issuecomment-1173773165

Comment: Basically I'm using the official one from here: https://github.com/salesforcecli/sfdx-cli/blob/main/dockerfiles/Dockerfile_full - but I have added two lines at the top - which I got from your file (thanks at this point for the hint): `RUN mkdir /.cache /.sf /.sfdx
RUN chmod 757 /.cache /.sf /.sfdx -R`- also I changed it to use the .tar file instead of NPM.